# Only one of three buttons working

Tags: android, android-button

Hey I am trying to get different buttons to open up different pages in a android            project but only on of the buttons is opening up a new page.

I am new to programming so my terminology may not be correct but I was following a youtube tutorial and it showed how to create a button and make it open up a new page. I tried to do this for multiple buttons but I think I am making the mistake in the main activity. Sorry if I haven't provided the write information to help me solve the problem.

```
package test.activity.today;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityTutorialActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

        }               
    });
}

public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question_button);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Question.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

        }               
    });
}


public void onCreate2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.owner_cost);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Owner.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should only have one `onCreate()` method.. check android [activity's life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to understand it

```
package test.activity.today;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityTutorialActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick (View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

    }               
});
Button question = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question_button);
question.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick (View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Question.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

    }               
});
Button ownerCost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.owner_cost);
ownerCost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick (View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Owner.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
}

}
```

Comment: This account is too new to accept that as the answer but you are correct my friend!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: you're welcome..don't forget to accept when possible so others can benefit from it too

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the `onCreate()` method... this method is called natively by Android and, thus, none of your other methods will get called (you'd have other problems if they were). To create more than one button, you need to add new buttons to your layout and then add them to `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to implement the onClick.

In your layout you can specify the function to call onClick

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonNext1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/back_color"
    android:onClick="RegistraterCompanyOnClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_next" />
```

Then in your activity you can filter which button by it's ID. See below.

```
public void RegistraterCompanyOnClick(View v){

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.imageButtonNext1:
        String cname = company.getText().toString();

        if (cname.length()== 0){

            message = getString(R.string.company_required);

            ShowDialog(message);

        }
        else{
            company_name =  company.getText().toString();

            VerifyClient(company_name);
        }

        break;
    case R.id.imageButtonInfo1:
        //message = getString(R.string.registration_info);

        message = "Device ID:\n" + deviceID;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ShowDialog(message);

        break;
    case R.id.imageButtonHelp1:

        message = getString(R.string.registration_contact);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ShowDialog(message);
        break;

    case R.id.imageButtonPrevious1:
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        resultIntent.putExtra("company_name",               company.getText().toString());
        resultIntent.putExtra("company_id", companyID);
        resultIntent.putExtra("location_name", location_name);
        resultIntent.putExtra("location_id", locationID);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, resultIntent);

        finish();
    default:
        break;
    }


}
```